# Displays someone else's user profile

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

Why, when I log in to the system and request a user profile, does it always show me the profile of only the first added user, and not the one who logged in? Where is the mistake?

routes:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const passport = require('passport')
const db = require("../config/db.config.js");
const User = db.users;

router.get('/get', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req,res) => {
    const error = {};
    User.findOne({user_id: req.user.user_id})
    .then((profile) => {
        if(!profile) {
            return res.status('404').send(error);
        }
        res.send(profile)
    })
    .catch(err => {return res.status(400).send(err)});
});


module.exports = router
```

passport.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt
const db = require("../config/db.config.js");
const User = db.users;

const opts = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY,
}

module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, async (payload, done) => {
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({user_id: payload.user_id})
      if (user) {
        done(null, user)
      } else {
        done(null, false)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }))
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what you get in `payload.user_id`?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `findOne` method correctly. To apply filtering you should use `{where: {...}}` object, see below:

```
User.findOne({where: {user_id: req.user.user_id}});
```

Without `where` sequelize doesn't recognize the object that you have passed to the filters as a filter and just returns the first record from the DB. See filtering examples [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html#-code-find--code----search-for-one-specific-element-in-the-database).